# Integrate ARMv8 Crypto accelerated SHA256 into existing C implementation function

Tags: assembly, cryptography, sha256, armv8

I am trying to employ an ARMv8/Aarch64 assembly implementation using hardware accelerated SHA256 transform/"data block ordering" through CPU Crypto extensions.

The problem is I do not understand the difference between the existing
`void sha256_transform(uint32_t *state, const uint32_t *block, int swap)` (1) https://github.com/fireworm71/veriumMiner/blob/main/algo/sha2.c#LC81
and the new ARMv8 sha256 function
`void sha256_block_data_order (uint32_t *ctx, const void *in, size_t num)` (2) https://github.com/glukolog/m-cpuminer-v2.1-armv8/blob/master/miner.h#L135 which I was trying to integrate with a preprocessor conditional to either leave the original code in if not **aarch64** *or* redirect the work to the HW accelerated `sha256_block_data_order` and merely leaving the original `sha256_transform` as a wrapper function so the numerous calls to it from other functions do not need much, if any editing.

I would like to draw attention to the `int swap` parameter for `sha256_transform` which the original C implementation takes as a conditional doing something to the block data parameter where as the `sha256_block_data_order` parameter in the same position seems to have something to do with the "number of blocks" and not related. In my most recent attempt I left the "int swap" code in before calling `sha256_block_data_order` so the data would be manipulated as originally intended and also tried to do casting in its function call thinking that was the culprit behind it all...below is the code I wrote recently for use inside `void sha256_transform(uint32_t *state, const uint32_t *block, int swap)`

```
#if defined(__aarch64__)

    uint32_t W[64];
    uint32_t S[8];
    int i;

    // 1. Prepare message schedule W.
    if (swap) {
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            W[i] = swab32(block[i]);
        } else
        memcpy(W, block, 64);
        for (i = 16; i < 64; i += 2) {
            W[i]   = s1(W[i - 2]) + W[i - 7] + s0(W[i - 15]) + W[i - 16];
            W[i+1] = s1(W[i - 1]) + W[i - 6] + s0(W[i - 14]) + W[i - 15];
    }

sha256_block_data_order(state, (const unsigned char *) W, 1);

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        state[i] += S[i];
#else
```

For the last loop I have a guess its equivalent in another application where the ARMv8 `sha256_block_data_order` [is being used already](https://github.com/glukolog/m-cpuminer-v2.1-armv8/blob/master/m7/sha2.c#L607) at least in its [C implementation](https://github.com/glukolog/m-cpuminer-v2.1-armv8/blob/master/m7/sha2.c#L184) but do not understand assembly well enough to see if the [same is being done there](https://github.com/glukolog/m-cpuminer-v2.1-armv8/blob/master/sha256-armv8-aarch64.S). `uint32_t S` is being used in the C implementation of `sha256_transform` but I cannot tell if its being altered in any way before the final loop in my code above.

In link (2) there is a declaration of `sha256_transform` however is not applicable though you can compare the inputs (the two separate applications share the same implementation of it) to `sha256_block_data_order` also declared there to see the difference.

In my various attempts to make this work, I am able to get it to compile without errors and run the cpuminer binary in benchmarking mode but when I have it do real work for a server, all results are rejected. Also, I only find single digit differences in performance (measured in hash rates). Would this suggest that even if I could get it to work correctly I am not going to see any worthwhile gains in performance?

I spent days on this and not being very experienced or skilled have resorted to asking here. Any feedback or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually managed to figure it out. See github fork repo if interested. Approximately 1% speed boost to hashing application on account of shrunken inline-able sha256 function. Along with better memcpy and dual issue optimization.

https://github.com/rollmeister/veriumMiner